# Getting this crash on my crash reporting tool

Tags: marketing-cloud, sfdcmobilesdk-android, mobilepush

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: averageBytesPerChar is greater than maxBytesPerChar
   at java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder.(CharsetEncoder.java)
   at java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoderICU.(CharsetEncoderICU.java)
   at java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoderICU.newInstance(CharsetEncoderICU.java:74)
   at java.nio.charset.CharsetICU.newEncoder(CharsetICU.java:27)
   at com.android.internal.util.FastXmlSerializer.setOutput(FastXmlSerializer.java:313)
   at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.writeMapXml(XmlUtils.java:184)
   at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.writeToFile(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:597)
   at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.access$800(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:51)
   at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$2.run(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:512)
   at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.enqueueDiskWrite(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:533)
   at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.access$100(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:51)
   at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl.commit(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:455)
   at com.exacttarget.etpushsdk.util.a.a(SourceFile:35)
   at com.exacttarget.etpushsdk.util.e.run(SourceFile:348)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

This crash is happening in the wild to all my app users in Exact Target Android SDK. Any idea on how to fix it?

build.gradle

```
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:9.4.0'
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.2@aar') {
    transitive = true
}

compile(name: 'etsdk', ext: 'aar')//We are on version 4.5.0 compile'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
```

Comment: You're going to have to 1) help me get this question unflagged and 2) provide me with the language preferences and/or character encodings that are causing the problem.

Comment: Can you please provide all of the dependencies from your `app/build.gradle`?

Comment: I have edited my question to update the dependencies

Comment: Do you have any insight into the character encodings on the affected devices?

Comment: Nope, not really. Unfortunately the tool we use doesn't show us the character encodings